# Firebase Android Offline crash #AskFirebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I close my app with enabled offline capabilities (setPersistenceEnabled) and I try to reopen, it will crash every time until i remove the setPersistenceEnable line.

I get this stack:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncaught exception in Firebase runloop (3.0.0). Please report to support@firebase.com
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagc$1$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:152)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5507)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                               at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:102)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: hardAssert failed: 
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzall.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzall.zzcq(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiw.zzb(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaiw.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaip.<init>(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzagc.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahh.zzry(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahq.zzcre(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahq.zza(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzahq$1.run(Unknown Source)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:154)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:269)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
                                                                               at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
                                                                               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Extra info:

Gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0"
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:9.4.0' 

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```